# Como atualizar uma FutureBuilder / ListView.builder a partir de um Inkwell em outra class

Tags: mobile, flutter, dart

Estou querendo atualizar uma lista de ativos, que foi recuperada a partir de um banco de daods SQFLITE, ele foi criado em FutureBuilder, e organizado em Card, que estão com o conteúdo dentro de um Inkwell, ao clicar no inkwell aparece uma caixa de dialogo com a opção de deletar aquele item, a exclusão funciona, mas a tela só atualiza depois que saio e volto para ela, depois do código executado no inkwell já adicionei setState, mas mesmo assim não funciona:

Código onde a lista é criada:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:minha_carteira/Modelos/Ativo.dart';
import 'package:minha_carteira/Screens/alert_tap_card.dart';
import 'package:minha_carteira/Screens/formulario.dart';
import 'package:minha_carteira/database/dao.dart';

class CarteiraBR extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  State<CarteiraBR> createState() => _CarteiraBRState();
}

class _CarteiraBRState extends State<CarteiraBR> {
  final Dao _dao = Dao();

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: const Text('Carteira Brasil'),
      ),
      body: FutureBuilder(
        future: _dao.findAll(),
        builder: (context, snapshot) {
          switch (snapshot.connectionState) {
           case ConnectionState.done:
              final List<Ativo> listaDeAcoes = snapshot.data as List<Ativo>;
              return ListView.builder(
                  itemCount: listaDeAcoes.length,
                  itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                    final Ativo ativo = listaDeAcoes[index];
                    return CriaCard(ativo);
                  });
          }
          return const Text('Erro desconhecido');
        },
      ),
      floatingActionButton: FloatingActionButton(
        child: const Icon(Icons.add),
        onPressed: () {
          Navigator.of(context)
              .push(
            MaterialPageRoute(
              builder: (context) => Formulario('Adiciona Ativo BR'),
            ),
          )
              .then((value) {
            setState(() {});
          });
        },
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Abaixo a classe criacard, que cria cada item da lista:

```
class CriaCard extends StatefulWidget {
  final Ativo ativo;

  CriaCard(this.ativo);

  @override
  State<CriaCard> createState() => _CriaCardState();
}

class _CriaCardState extends State<CriaCard> {
  final TextStyle meuEstilo = TextStyle(fontSize: 12);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Card(
      child: InkWell(
        onTap: () {
            showDialog(
              context: context,
              builder: (context) {
                return AlertTapCard(widget.ativo.id);
              },
            );
            setState(() {
              widget.createState();
            });
        },
        child: Padding(
          padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
          child: Column(
// Código omitido!!
```

Quando eu clico no floatActionButton para criar um novo ativo, ele atualiza a lista quando termino, pois vou em outra tela e volto, mas como para excluir chamo apenas uma AlertDialog  e não mudo de tela o elemento excluido não desaparece da tela.

Comment: Por favor, edite a pergunta para limitá-la a um problema específico com detalhes suficientes para identificar uma resposta adequada.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Consegui resolver o problema com gerenciador de estados Provider.
parece que eu estava errando no fato de que o setState só atualiza aquela classe e suas classes filhas, como CriaCard é Filha de FutureBuilder quando CriaCrard chamava setState só atualizava a si mesma e não seu pai, FutureBuilder.
Com um gerenciador de estados Provider consegui resolver o problema.
Como tive de modificar muitas classes e códigos para adicionar (tive de fazer um curso de Provider primeiro(risos)) não estou postando o código todo aqui pois ficaria muito grande, aos que tiverem o mesmo problema sugiro pesquisar sobre o assunto.

Comment: Sua resposta pode ser melhorada adicionando informações fundamentais. Basta [edit] para adicionar mais detalhes, como citações ou documentação para que outras pessoas possam confirmar que sua resposta está correta. Você pode encontrar mais informações sobre como escrever boas respostas [na Central de Ajuda](/help/how-to-answer).